# Native base select box open from bottom

Tags: react-native, native-base

i'm using native base select box. if i click the select box. it open from bottom of the tab .. how to fix it .. means it should be open as a normal dropdown.

```
<Select
 selectedValue={value}
 minWidth="200"
 accessibilityLabel="Choose Role"
 placeholder="Choose Role"
 _selectedItem={{
      bg: "teal.600",
      endIcon: <CheckIcon size="5" />,
       }}
  mt={1}
  variant="native-base"
  borderWidth={1}
   borderRadius={2}
 defaultValue={value}
  value={value}
  onValueChange={(value) => onChange(value)}
 onBlur={onBlur}
>
 <Select.Item label="Picker" value="picker" />
 <Select.Item label="Packer" value="packer" />
```

[image]